# mod_rewrite and SEO friendly with redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /Home [R,NC] 
RewriteRule ^Home$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

but if I go to mydomain.com/index.php is still accesible and displaying the same content of mydomain.com/Home. That's ok for me, but is not well for SEO because I have duplicated content, so Is there a way to do a redirect and rewrite the URL to /Home when I access the /index.php ?
I try with

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /Home [R,NC] 
RewriteRule ^Home$ /index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /Home [R=301,L]
```

but It is in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than fiddling with the deep dungeons of mod-rewrite/htaccess you should go for [canonical links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) if it is indeed the same content.